# Prove the complex function is entire

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the function:

$$ f(z) = e^{x^2 - y^2}  (\cos 2xy + i \sin 2xy )=e^{z^2} $$

How can I prove that it is analytic everywhere in the complex plane?

Comment: Hint: If $f$ and $g$ is entire then $f(g(z))$ is also entire. A more direct way is to look at the power-series $e^{z^2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} z^{2n}$. If you can show that radius of convergence is infinite then you are done.

Comment: It's a composition of the entire functions $z \mapsto z^2$ and $w \mapsto \exp w$, and so it is entire. If you don't know some of these facts you can prove them using the Cauchy-Riemann equations. (In fact you can just check $f$ directly with the CR equations, but this is a less useful fact.)

Comment: If I wanna use CR equuation ...should I applies it on this form $f(z) = e^{x^2 - y^2} \cos 2xy + i e^{x^2 - y^2} \sin 2xy $ .?

Comment: If you want to use equations that involve partial derivatives in $x$ and $y$, then you need a formula written in terms of $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 2):

In the form $e^{x^2 - y^2}  (\cos 2xy + i \sin 2xy )$, you can easily figure out the $u$ and $v$ functions for CR equations (just remember that $e^{x^2 + y^2}$ is purely real). So all you have to do is prove that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = -\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$. If you just take $e^z$, you can't clearly see what does the the real-part function $u$ or the imaginary-part function $v$ look like.